# cannot open local files synchronized by sharepoint workspaces

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2010, windows-sbs

I have a client who is using SharePoint on Small Business Server 2011 to store a large collection of .png files.  He is then using SharePoint workspaces to synchronize the files back to his workstation.  The trouble is, he cannot open the files.

He has permission to access the files, because he can browse to them in SharePoint (the web interface) and download them one at a time.  He can browse to them in Windows Explorer (via the Workspaces directory in his user profile.  He can insert the file into a Word document.  But he cannot open the file directly from within Explorer or from within the SharePoint Workspaces client application.  It also won't let him copy the files to another location on his computer.  He is not trying to make changes to the files, just view them.  Why can't we open these files?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to view the user permissions specifically? Site Actions-Site Setting Check Permissions and then enter the user name.  If you cannot access this, a SharePoint Admin or other admin may need to check this.

Any other things like a warning banner at the top of the page?

Can someone check the SP logs for possible issues?

Comment: The user in question is in the Owners group with "Full Control".  I don't see any errors.  I will look into the logs

Comment: Where can we find the SP logs?  Sorry, we're new to SharePoint